# How to XOR two binary numbers having different lengths?

Tags: logic, arithmetic

If we have:

**x = 1101** and **y = 101**

How to XORing these numbers?

Comment: Why would you want to XOR these numbers?

Comment: You already asked essentially the same question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31520787/781723.   It would have been better to mention the comments you already got over there when you asked it here, and link to the pre-existing question on Stack Overflow in this post.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to interpret this XOR.

The most common one is that you XOR bit-wise, and that these strings represent numbers, so adding 0 to the left doesn't change their value.

Then $5 \equiv 101 \to 0101$  and then you XOR bit-wise.

```
x 1101
y 0101
------- XOR
  1000
```

which gives 8, if we are talking about unsigned numbers.
However, the above depends on **my** understanding of **your** system. Change the assumptions, change the results.

Comment: What if we have two binary numbers first one 8-bits and the second one is 55-bits. Is there another method to xorring them withot add "0"?

Comment: what is the aim of XOR'ing them?

Answer (score 0):

Look first you should know is your numbers in Signage system value or not if they are in Signage system value you should do some stuff        1_ your number is positive (it means the last bit is zero such as 101 this number is -3) so in this case if you want to increase the number of bits you should add 1 to last bit . in your case the number 101 turns into 1101 and 1101 xor 101 turns into 1101 xor 1101 and the answer is 0000                      2_ but if your numbers were normal (not in Signage system value mode) very easy you add zero to last bit . in your case        1101 xor 101 become 1101 xor 0101 and the answer is 1000

Comment: XOR is a logical operation, so it doesn't make too much sense to sign-extend numbers being XORed.

Answer (score 0):

if x and y are integer values, then

```
int XOR(int x,int y)
{   
    return x^y;
}
```

whereas, if x and y are strings, then

```
string XOR(string x,string y)
{
    auto temp= bitset<4>(x) ^ bitset<3>(y);
    string u;
    u=temp.to_string();
    return u;
}
```

Comment: In the notation of your 2nd code block, the question is about `bitset<4>(x) ^ bitset<3>(y)`.